# How to upload a PNG/JPG to a postgresql DB with python

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I am starting a project where I want to upload a PNG or a JPG to a table in my postgresql DB. The problem is that I don't know what libraries I should use. I am able to insert / update 'normal' data into my table. Can you give me any advice on what I should focus on first?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you give me any advice on what I should focus on first?

*upload a PNG/JPG to a postgresql DB* is certain example of storing *binary file in database*, postgresql has [article](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB) pertaining to it.

Generally there are two main distinct approaches to that:

- using column of type designed for holding binary data, `bytea` in case of postgresql
- converting binary data to text and then storing like any other long text

First does require less memory, but not all programming tools for postgresql does support it smoothly (according to author of linked article Python & .Net do), for second [base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648.html) encoding is most commonly, which is widely available for various programming language (in `python` it is [part of standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)), however you might elect to use any other encoding, as long as it turns sequence of bytes into text and such generated text into original bytes.

Comment: So when I convert my file into a base64 string and insert it into my table it appears as a normal PNG inside it? 
Edit: I just realised the type of my field is a "bytea" so I will probably just go with your first suggestion. Thank you

Comment: @Fabi99v Tables are just data.  They don't have "appearances".  Turning data into an appearance is the clients job.